# kinect depth and rgb registration

Tags: ros, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im able to have rgb point cloud by registration using openni rqt_reconfigure. however, i want to access a pixel in rgb image (camera image_color topic) and find its depth. Which topic should i subscribe depth_registered/image_raw or depth_registered/rect.

I looked at the http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html . There is no depth in it. How can i access depth value

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216729/kinect-depth-and-rgb-registration/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect has the problem that not every pixel have an depth value.  So it is not easy the get the depth of an pixel.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-08-29**:
hi, i want to save 1 frame of depth registered image raw but it gives me error when i run image_view and right click to save 1 frame because its not in brg8 format. how can i save a depth map